# Get image path from drive letter on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I'd like to get the backing file path(like .iso or .vhd file) from a mounted volume.
This is my code.

```
HANDLE hVolume = CreateFileW(L"\\.\V:", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, nullptr);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hVolume)
{
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query;
    memset(&query, 0, sizeof(query));
    query.PropertyId = StorageAdapterProperty;
    query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
    STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR result;
    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    bResult = DeviceIoControl(hVolume, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &query, sizeof(query),
        &result, sizeof(result), &dwSize, nullptr);
    if (bResult)
    {
        if (BusTypeFileBackedVirtual == result.BusType)
        {
            //find out the image path
        }
    }
    
    CloseHandle(hVolume);
}
```

I googled a lot and cannot find the answer. I also notice that "get-diskimage -devicepath" command in powershell shows the image path, but I have no idea how it's implemented.
Thanks!

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but definitely too long for a comment.

Getting the definition of the command outputs some interesting things (cut for brevity):

```
PS > (get-command get-diskimage).Definition

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ByImagePath', PositionalBinding=$false)]

    [OutputType([Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance])]
[OutputType('Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_DiskImage')]

[...snip...]
```

The output shows the use of the [`MSFT_DiskImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/msft-diskimage) and (not shown above) [`MSFT_DiskImageToVolume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/msft-diskimagetovolume) WMI classes.

The documentation says the the MOF file is `Storagewmi.mof`. The binary modules are often named after the MOF file, in this case it's `%SystemRoot%\system32\StorageWmi.dll`.

I quickly focused reverse engineering  the `BuildDiskImageObject` function which signature is:

- `BuildDiskImageObject(PCWSTR Path, unsigned int, struct _MI_Context *, struct _MSFT_DiskImage *)`

The [`_MSFT_DiskImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/msft-diskimage) structure is an output parameter, filled within the function. I contains the full path to the image disk.

The function does a lot of leverage to insure corner cases are processed as needed, but the gist is:

- Determine the storage type (used by `OpenVirtualDisk`).
- Call [`OpenVirtualDisk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-openvirtualdisk).
- Call internal function `UpdateDiskImageObject`

  - `UpdateDiskImageObject(HANDLE VirtualDiskHandle, struct _MSFT_DiskImage *)`

In `UpdateDiskImageObject`:

- [`GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-getvirtualdiskphysicalpath)
- Call `CreateFileW` on the disk path returned by `GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath`.
- DeviceIoControl() (on the handle returned by CreateFile) used to send IOCTL 0x2D1080 ( I guess it's [`IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_storage_get_device_number) IOCTL).
- Call [`GetVirtualDiskInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-getvirtualdiskinformation).
- Fill the `_MSFT_DiskImage` structure with all the information gathered in this function.

Since the WMI implementation is trying hard to not fail and doing quite a good deal of things, I would go with interrogating the WMI classes rather than reimplementing the wheel.